# How to insert a query result into a new table

Tags: sql-server, insert, copy

I would like to insert the query result into a new table to manipulate it easily, right now I can get the query result but I'm not able to insert it into a new table, this is the query I want to insert into:

```
with Errors as 
(
    select [NOW], (left([ERROR],10)) as Error 
    from [MESF_2].[dbo].[Machine_Error]

    union all

    select [NOW], [cce] 
    from [MESF_2].[dbo].[Server]
)
select 
    [now], [error], 
    datediff(second, LAG([now],1,null) over (order by [now] asc), [now]) as [Delta in seconds] 
from Errors


Create table [MESF_2].[dbo].[MESF2_Data_Summary] 
(
    [Now] datetime, 
    [Error] nvarchar(255),
    [Delta in seconds] integer 
);
```

I want to insert the results into the table `[MESF2_Data_Summary]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the table first, then run:

```
with Errors as 
(
    .... (the CTE from your post) ....
)
insert into [MESF_2].[dbo].[MESF2_Data_Summary] (now, error, [Delta in seconds])
    select
        [now], [error], 
        datediff(second, LAG([now],1,null) over (order by [now] asc), [now]) as [Delta in seconds] 
    from Errors
```

Answer (score 1):

USE SQL server's insert into select:

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: This will *only work* if the table doesn't exist yet. If it does exist - this will abort with an error ...